# How do you write a Javascript Regex that matches if file extension is not within (exe|js|htaccess)

Tags: javascript, regex, file-upload, file-extension

I'm trying to write a javascript regexp for a blacklist of file extensions.  I'm using a jquery plugin that has an option for acceptable file types that takes a regex, but rather than maintain a whitelist we would like to maintain a blacklist.  So I need the regex to only match if the string doesn't contain certain file extensions.  Currently there is a regex we use to whitelist photo extensions on our photo upload:

```
/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
```

For our document upload we would like to simply do a blacklist, but I haven't been able to make the ?! delimeter work.  So for the sake of an example how would I reverse this regex to match as long as the file extension doesn't contain gif, jpg, jpeg, png?

I've tried several different ways of using the ?!, but nothing I've tried has worked properly.  Heres some examples of what I have tried unsuccessfully:

```
/(\.|\/)(?!gif|jpe?g|png)$/i

/(\.|\/)(?!(gif|jpe?g|png))$/i
```

Essentially I need this regex to always return true unless the blacklisted file extensions are matched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>This works:</strike>

```js
/\.(?!(?:exe|js|htaccess)$)|\/(?!(?:exe|js|htaccess)$)/i
```

I think it's because the "match only if not followed by" doesn't like parentheses before it, but I'm not sure.

This new regex now works with the parentheses and multiple extensions:

```js
/^.*(\.|\/)(?!(exe|js|htaccess)$)(?![^\.\/]*(\.|\/))/i
```

However, to allow files with no extension, this must be used:

```js
/(^.*(\.|\/)(?!(exe|js|htaccess)$)(?![^\.\/]*(\.|\/)))|(^[^\.]+$)/i
//                                                     ^^^^^^^^^
//                                  This part matches a name without any dots
```

Looking at the complexity of that regex, I suggest that you implement something server-side or use another plugin.

Comment: Thanks! This is a bit odd to me for a regexp, but it works without modifying the plugin which is what matters.

Comment: That's weird.  Also, you forgot to escape the `.` in `.htaccess` :)

Comment: It looks like you're missing a $ on the first group. This works perfect for me: `/\.(?!(?:exe|js|.htacess)$)/i`

Comment: Theres one more flaw I'm trying to resolve with this regexp... It works if there is only one file extension, but not if there is multiple.  For example it properly blocks .js, but doesn't block .min.js

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! The regex works great.  I agree that it's very complex, but the [jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin is pretty great with lots of custom implementation hours invested in it that can't go to waste.  There will be server side checks as well, but I needed the JS regex for the best user experience possible.

Answer (score 2):

Hack the jQuery plugin to accept a callback function instead of (or in addition to) a regular expression. Use the negation operator (`!`) and the positive regular expression to supply an appropriate callback. And write a mail to the maintainer of the plugin asking him to accept your patch.

Comment: My goal is to not need to modify the plugin.  In some circumstances that we use it we want just the whitelist, and in another we want the blacklist.  It would be nice hack a blacklist option together for it, but I am hoping to save time by simply reversing the whitelist.

Comment: One quibble: ! is not a negation operator.  `(?! )` is a negative lookahead assertion.  There is no negation operator outside of a character class.

Comment: I think JDUtil was referring to using the boolean negation `!` when testing the regex, not as part of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a regex expert, but something like this appears to work: `/\.(exe|js|htaccess)$/ig.test(filename)` true results when the file is on your blacklist.

```
var shouldblockUpload = /\.(exe|js|htaccess)$/ig.test(filename);
//Inform user illegal upload
```

You can also explicitly only allow certain filetypes through the accept attribute on file inputs to help hint users to the right ones.

Comment: due to the use of a jquery plugin for fileuploads that I am trying to avoid modifying I need false to be the result when the file is on my blacklist.  Essentially I need this regex to always return true unless the blacklisted file extensions are matched.